# How can I specify end time for a quartz.net simple trigger on minute recurrence?

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have the below simple trigger which runs every 60 minutes. I want this to end on a given date. How can  I achieve this?

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                              .WithDescription("Minute")
                              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                              .WithIntervalInMinutes(minutes))
                              .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSeconds, StartDate, StartMonth, StartYear))
                              .Build();
```

I tried the .EndAt after the .StartAt line. But it doesn't work. Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use "EndAt" **and** "RepeatForever" together:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                          .WithDescription("Minute")
                          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                          .WithIntervalInMinutes(minutes)
                                        .RepeatForever())
                          .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSeconds, StartDate, StartMonth, StartYear))
                          .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(endMinnutes,endSeconds,endDate, endMonth, endYear))
                          .Build();
```

The default behavior of scheduler is repeatedcount 0.
when repeatedcount is 0, the method "FinalFireTimeUtc" returns the start date. you will stop raising events only when "FinalFireTimeUtc" returns null.

To achieve the behavior you are looking for, you have to use "EndAt" and "RepeatForever" together